# Right Clicking A File To Open It With A .NET Program

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

For example, if I made a compressor using the .NET Framework. How would I be able to right click a folder and open it in the compressor to compress it?

Comment: What is the point of "open with .Net program". Do you mean how to integrate your program with shell or how to register your soft in operation system?

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate file type (based on extension) with your compressor application.

For details check the article [Understanding MS Windows File Associations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749986.aspx).

It requires some registry entry modifications, that can be done from installer application.

Answer (score 1):

Add a key under `HKCR / filetype / Shell` **(where filetype is the filetype associated with the file extension, e.g. jpegfile)**

For more details check this: [Add a context menu on right-click](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10104/Add-a-context-menu-to-the-Windows-Explorer)